# Solving a weighted network flow using Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, graph-theory, linear-programming, graph-traversal

I have a bipartite graph (guy and girl notes) where nodes are connected with weighted edges (how compatible the girl-guy pair is) and each node has a capacity of 5 (each guy/girl can get matched to 5 people of the opposite gender). I need to find the best possible matching to maximize the weights.

This can be formulated as a weighted network flow - each guy is a source of 5 units, each girl is a sink of 5 units, and each possible arc has capacity of 1 unit. The problem can be solved either using linear programming, or a graph traversal algorithm (such as  Ford–Fulkerson).

I'm currently looking into possible solutions using Neo4j - does anybody have any idea how to go about it? (or should I just go with a linear programming solution...)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is something like this. Find the five most `COMPATIBLE` relationships ordering by the weight of the relationship in descending order and then create them as a separate relationship `MATCH`.

```
match (guy:Guy)-[rel:COMPATIBLE]->(girl:Girl)
where guy.id = 'xx'
with guy, rel, girl
order by rel.weight desc
limit 5
create (guy)-[:MATCH]->(girl)
```

Comment: Thanks Dave! However, this will give you the best match for the first few guys, but the rest of the guys will get either poor matches, or no matches at all. Weighted network flow is an optimization problem that tries  maximize the weight of  all the matches

Comment: This is a good answer to a different question. I think that the question is unclear, but I looked up Ford-Fulkerson and I think you need to maximize return for all nodes. I don't think it is possible with straight Cypher.

Comment: Right - i added the where clause to the cypher to focus on just one guy.